# Ubuntu can't resize partition /boot

Tags: ubuntu

I can't resize the partition boot, I looked on many tuts but none worked. I don't know why. I want to resize sda5 and take 1gb from it then give the 1gb to /Boot

[image]

who I typed sudo fdisk -l in terminal:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d4537

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   312580095   156039169    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   312580095   156039168   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 157.6 GB, 157642915840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19165 cylinders, total 307896320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 2139 MB, 2139095040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4177920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Why are you want to resize /boot/ partition ?

Comment: what version of ubuntu/gparted? From what I understand LVM support is limited in GParted and only a recent addition, but I would make sure I had the latest version of GParted

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can resize a partition that is currently in use. You may have to boot from a USB or dual boot to resize the partition.